# jQuery Dialog not opening second time after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a DIV that is defined as a dialog to cancel a request:

```
 <div id="first">
      //first content to load
 </div>
 <div id="second" style="display:none">
      // next content
 </div>
 <div id="CancelDialog" style="display:none">Are you sure?</div>
 <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" />
 <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="next();" />
```

and it is initialized:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#CancelDialog").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                     // calls a cancel function
                },
                "No" : function() {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
          }
      });

    <script type="text/javascript"
         function next() {
           $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '@Url.Action("ShowNext"),
              success: function(data) {
                  $("#first").hide();
                  $("#second").html(data);
                  $("#second").show();
              }
           });
        }
  </script>
```

My cshtml page has three other DIVs that are loaded from an ajax call from partial views.  The cancel button works the first time before any ajax call is made but not again after the first DIV is hidden and the second one loaded.  Nothing happens after the ajax call.  Is this normal?

How do I get it to work on each of the ajax calls and subsequent DIVs being shown and/or hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you load content dynamically, you probably have duplicate id's on your page (e.g. `id="btnCancel"` more than once).

jQuery and Javascript can only see the first match for ID-based searches.

You need to make sure they are unique (or use classes instead).

*If you show the complete page, it will help identify the specifics* :)

Comment: @Dean.DePue: In your example, your dialog `div` does not contain the buttons??? They follow it. Is your HTML correct?

Comment: Sorry, but yes the buttons are in their own DIV that is always shown and not hidden.

Comment: @Dean.DePue: are you able to add a JSFiddle with the entire DOM HTML after loading the divs (taken from the Chrome F12 DOM inspector so it reflects the HTML after Ajaxing)?

Comment: I have found an interesting approach - I had set the partial view with loading the jquery JS file because the datepicker was not working.  If I take out the load of the jquery file, the cancel button works, but now the datepicker does not.  Why do I have to reload the jquery file in order for the dateoicker of the call to the dialog have to work?

Comment: You should avoid having scripts in dynamically loaded partial pages. Instead the loader needs to apply any add-ins (like datepicker) to the loaded panel (e.g. based on specific common classes on the elements).

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by 'loader needs to apply any add-in'.  How do I do that to make sure the jquery calls for the datepicker are called?  When I click on the text box I get a failure in jquery,validate,js,

Comment: The "loader" in this case is the ajax call... Apply your datapicker to matching elements in the loaded region. e.g. in the `success:` function have  `$("#second").html(data).find('.datepicker').datePicker();` (using your own class names of course)

Comment: I'm getting the same error in jquery.validate after I add the call $("#second").html(data).find('#DOB').datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});

Comment: Are you able to provide a complete sample page? `jquery.validate` also does not like dynamically loaded/removed fields.